# Hide stdin data from user running script?

Tags: python, stdin, encapsulation

I am constructing a problem on [spoj.com](http://spoj.com). User has to submit a script that will be pre-appended with a code of mine that will provide him with functions that he has to use. A template of this kind:

```
def youmustusethis(maptask, reducetask):
  data = sys.stdin.readlines()
  return reduce(reducetask, map(maptask, data))

##### USER WRITES CODE BELOW #####
....
```

The funny thing is: users are way too often hacking output than solving problems. I anticipate that people will just ignore the functionality and read stdin directly and process it completely ignoring the "framework" I provide.

Is there a way to hide stdin data from the bottom-half of the script in a way that will force the use of my framework to process it?

Comment: no great way to block access to `stdin`, but you could always set `sys.stdin` to something else.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- If a user wants to parse stdin themself, why not let them?

Comment: SPOJ is an problem-solving site. I need to verify that user learned how to use certain framework (MapReduce). When you write an exam, you are scored for the method you apply, not for "answer is 5.". I need to enforce that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is - don't. There are many things you need to consider in order to make this work properly. Consider the following snippet:

```
sys.stdin = open("/dev/stdin")
```

With [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes), this might get even more difficult. Instead of hacking around trying to obfuscate a rather big attack vector, I would suggest looking for a sandboxing/restricted Python enviroments that somebody already created. My guess is that libraries for IRC bots should already be doing this properly.

Comment: I found that it's even worse. User can leak data out of a mapper, process it outside of the "framework" and then leak data in through a reducer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an odd request. You should probably just write a note saying "don't access sys.stdin" or something similar.

Off the top of my head, you could either close sys.stdin, or re-assign it.
For example:

```
_stdin = sys.stdin
sys.stdin = None
```

[edit: I feel I should mention, that this is generally a bad idea.]

Comment: I considered saving the original `sys.stdin`, but since it looks like the user can read the original code I think that just leads to them accessing `_stdin` instead.

Comment: Adam is right. Python does not block access to "private" variables so user can just hack whatever variable there is that he can find.

Comment: The lack of private members is somewhat indicative of python's philosophy, specifically "we're all adults here" -- meaning that "preventative programming" is generally frowned on. If the programmer decides to open the hood, and tinker with the inner workings, they are responsible for the results, good or bad.  If you document things well, explaining what to do, and how to do it properly, it's not your fault they ignored you.

Comment: you've mentioned some kind of framework... it is possible to load a module which causes side-effects, like replacing sys.stdin with (from Adam's answer) a StringIO instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
import sys
try:
    import StringIO as io # python2
except ImportError:
    import io             # python3

# your functions go here

sys.stdin = io.StringIO()
```

This will make normal file operations not fail if your user tries to use `stdin`, but also not pass. This may be difficult for your users to diagnose, however.

Compare:

```
def fails_loudly():
    """throws AttributeError"""
    sys.stdin = None
    return sys.stdin.read()

def fails_silently():
    """returns empty string"""
    sys.stdin = io.StringIO()
    return sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: A word of caution ... Things which "don't fail, but also not pass" tend to be _really_ tricky to debug ;-).

Comment: Agreed, but this might be the intended result! :)

Comment: Thank you, Adam. This was an interesting lesson to me. Unfortunately this does not seem to solve the problem at hand. I need to store stdin data somewhere to be able to process it while blocking access to it from user-code below. I should not block access to it for myself. xP

Comment: Yeah there's no way to do that, really, outside of threading with a lock.

Comment: Threading with a lock? Was that a parallel joke (pun intended)? xD

Comment: @ArekBulski I don't have time to tinker and get a working prototype, but building some object that would require you to acquire a lock to access a file object, replace `sys.stdin` with it, then use a thread to run all your background calculations with that lock.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution. Apparently I can show the user one template and pre-append a different template (slightly different) so, I tell the user "use this":

```
def youmustusethis(maptask, reducetask):
  data = sys.stdin.readlines()
  return reduce(reducetask, map(maptask, data))

##### USER WRITES CODE BELOW #####
```

while I pre-append something like:

```
def youmustusethis(maptask, reducetask):
  DATA_48fsnk29s73kdhx7292k = sys.stdin.readlines()
  return reduce(reducetask, map(maptask, DATA_48fsnk29s73kdhx7292k))

##### USER WRITES CODE BELOW #####
```

Note the code is ran by SPOJ judge, user is only shown AC/WA and no stdout or stderr. Unless the user can guess the variable name, it's doubtful he will be able to find it.